# Are all trigonometric polynomials from the 3-torus to the 3-sphere homotopically trivial?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, polynomials, trigonometric-polynomials

I'm looking at maps from the 3-torus $\mathbb{T}^3\simeq (\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})^3$ to the 3-sphere $\mathbb{S}_3\subset \mathbb{R}^4$.

I understand that, according to [Hopf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_theorem), continuous maps from $\mathbb{T}^3$ to $\mathbb{S}_3$ are homotopic iff they have equal degree.

And, considering $\mathbb{T}^3/\{(x,y,z)/xyz=0 \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}_3$, there certainly are continuous maps from $\mathbb{T}^3$ to $\mathbb{S}_3$ that are not homotopically trivial.

My problem is that I am only allowed trigonometric polynomials, such as $f:(x,y,z)\mapsto (\sin x \sin y \sin z, \cos x \sin y \sin z, \cos y \sin z,\cos z)$, which, as far as I can tell, has degree 0.

To clarify, what I mean by "trigonometric polynomial" is a map $$f:\left(\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{(R/2\pi\mathbb{Z})}^3&\to&\mathbb{R}^4\\
(x,y,z)&\mapsto & (f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z),f_4(x,y,z))\\
\end{array}\right)$$ such that each component $f_i(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial in $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\sin y$, $\cos y$, $\sin z$ and $\cos z$.  The image of $f$ has to be included in $\mathbb{S}_3$, so for every $(x,y,z)$, $\sum\limits_i f_i(x,y,z)^2 = 1$

I then have two questions:

1. Is it true, as I suspect, that all trigonometric polynomials from $\mathbb{T}^3$ to $\mathbb{S}_3$ are homotopic to a constant function?
2. I also suspect that, although there is a continuous path from $f$ to a constant function, such a path cannot be made entirely of trigonometric polynomials.  Am I right?  Could it be true, for instance, that any trigonometric polynomial function $g$ from $\mathbb{T}^3$ to $\mathbb{S}_3$ whose image has an nonempty interior is onto?

Comment: What are the defnition of trigonometric polynomials here?

Comment: I edited the question in order to clarify what I mean by that.

Comment: Did you try the 2-dimensional case? Maybe that's easier and could shed some light.

Comment: Yes, I did try the 2-dimensional case, and I see no reason to believe that there be a trigonometric polynomial from $\mathbb{T}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}_n$ that isn't homotopic to a constant function for any $n>1$.

For instance, for $n=2$, I found the mapping $(\sin(y/2) \sin x,\frac{\sin y}{2}(1-\cos x), \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos x)(1-\cos y) - 1)$. It is not homotopically trivial, but also not a trigonometric polynomial, because of this $\sin(y/2)$ that seems unavoidable; but I do not have the beginning of an argument as to why one couldn't get rid of it.

Comment: @VincentNesme:  Hmm.  The function $f(y) = \sin(y/2)$ is not $2\pi$-periodic because $f(y+2\pi) = -f(y)$, so your proposed mapping of $\mathbb{T}^2\to S^2$ is not well-defined.  Meanwhile, if you replace $y$ by $2y$ in your formula, so as to get a well-defined mapping, that mapping does have degree $0$, so it's homotopically trivial.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Sorry, I should have written $|\sin(y/2)|$ instead (I was thinking of $y\in[0;2\pi]$).
If I replace $y$ with $2y$, it does have degree $0$, but the whole point is I'm trying to avoid that situation...
either my function is a trigonometric polynomial, or it has nonzero degree, but I cannot have both. Is it because of my lack of imagination or is it because it is impossible?

Comment: Any polynomial map from an $n$-torus to $S^n$ is nullhomotopic, if $n \geq 2$. This was shown by Loday, Applications algébriques du tore dans la sphère et de $S^p\times S^q$ dans $S^{p+q}$, by K-theoretic methods (using the Bass-Heller-Swan theorem and Bott periodicity)

Comment: @JohannesEbert This is a perfect answer to the title and to my first question, this should be more than a comment.... Any hint about my second question? I realize I was wrong in thinking that any polynomial function $\mathbb{T}^3$ to $S^3$ whose image has an nonempty interior could be onto, but the first part of the question remains a mystery to me.

Comment: @JohannesEbert: And if I may push my luck... what I'm really interested in are polynomial maps from $\mathbb{T}^n$ to $SU(m)$ (it just so happens that when $m=2$, $SU(2)\simeq S^3$). Any thought about that one?